# Tabs in ViewPager inside vertical ScrollView won't scroll verticaly

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollview, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have tabs in ViewPager that inside vertical ScrollView. Horizontal swipes performed successfully. When I try vertical swipes, nothing happens.

FragmentActivity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/background_all_screen">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/llButtons">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/all"
            android:onClick="onClickAll"
            style="@style/button.blue"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/llButtons"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="48dip"
                    style="@style/PagerSlidingTabStrip"
                    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"/>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Probably I have a conflict between a ScrollView and a ViewPager.

**UPDATE**
Solution with ScrollViews in fragments is nice, but I want something like that:

[image: User can see tabs] [image: User can't see tabs]

User can't see tabs content in second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to have a view pager inside a scrollview? My suggestion is to use scrollviews as layout containers for the fragments of the viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your layout in this way:

as you do not have any widget inside the scrollView and i think everything is in your fragment layouts  move your scroll view to the layout of every fragment that you send to the viewpager and make it as a root . so in this way every fragment scroll vertically and you can also change them by viewpager.

Hope help !